# Python: How to determine if a string has an exact match with any string from the list

Tags: python, regex, string, string-matching, exact-match

Assume that I have the list of phrases to compare against as:
["hello", "hi", "bye"]

I want to return true if my text has any of this words in it, but with exact match. Meaning that: `hi there, how are you?` returns true, but `hithere, how are you?` returns false.

So far I have the below code:

```py
phrases = ['hello', 'hi', 'bye']    
    
def match(text: str) -> bool:
    if any(ext in text for ext in phrases):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

But it returns true for both inputs.

I also found out about this below function which returns the exact matches from the string, but I want to compare against a list of phrases, not a single string. I know I can iterate through the list of words and check one by one, but hoping to find a solution that is better performing.

```py
import re
print(re.findall('\\bhello\\b', "hellothere, how are you?"))
```

Update: By exact match, I mean word boundary. That can be space, punctuation, etc. Just like what `\b` is

Comment: You need to be very clear about what constitutes an exact match. What about `'Hi. How are you?'`? Or `'Hi8 video'`? And `'Hi, how are you?'` or `'Um, hi?'`? (by the way don't worry too much about performance before you have something that works, especially with something as simple and quick as a match operation like this. "Performance" is not your most pressing problem at this point.)

Comment: @Grismar, that's an excellent question. When comparing words, does punctuation disqualify a word or not. For example, does ```'hi' == 'hi,'``` return false or true? How about ```'Hi'=='hi'```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex of the form `r"(abc|ef|xxx)"` will match with "abc", "ef", or "xxx". You can create this regex by using the string concatenation as below.
Note `re.search` returns None if no match is found.

```py
import re

phrases = ['hello', 'hi', 'bye']
def match(text):
  r = re.search(r'\b({})\b'.format("|".join(phrases)), text)
  return r is not None

match("hi there, how are you?"), match("hithere, how are you?")
# (True, False)
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to first [`split()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/split) the sentence into words, then [`strip()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/strip) any punctuation marks and alike for each word and finally check if that word matches a word in the list. Actually you should not use a list but a [Set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) which will enable lookups in constant (`O(1)`) time instead of linear (`O(n)`) time as is the case with lists.

```py
phrases = ['hello', 'hi', 'bye']
phraseSet = set(phrases)

def match(text: str, word_set: set[str]) -> bool:
    words = text.split(" ")
    for word in words:
        stripped = word.strip(".?!,:")
        if stripped in word_set:
            return True
    return False

print(match("hi there, how are you?", phraseSet))
print(match("hithere, how are you?", phraseSet))
```

Obviously one could write the above solution in a more pythonic way.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact needs, you can tweak this, but I think this does what you need:

```
import re

phrases = ['hello', 'hi', 'bye']
text = "Hi there, how are you? How did that Hi8 turn out? Hi, can you hear me? Hello? Uh... Bye!"
expression = rf'(?:^|(?<=\s))(?:{"|".join(phrases)})(?=[,\.!?;:\s]|$)'

result = re.findall(expression, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['Hi', 'Hi', 'Hello', 'Bye']
```

About that regular expression:

- `(?:^|(?<=\s))` says: in a non-capturing group (`(?: )`), check that there's the start of the line, or the previous character is a space character.
- `(?:{"|".join(phrases)})` Since the expression is an f-string (and a raw string, `rf'something'`) the part between `{}` gets replaced by evaluating the Python expression, so `hello|hi|bye` in this case. The expression will match any of the words, in a non-capturing group.
- `(?=[,\.!?;:\s]|$)` and at the end, there's a lookahead checking that the next character is either interpunction or a space, or the end of the string follows. (Note that the `.` needs to be escaped with a backslash for the regex engine, otherwise it would match "any character")

Comment: Other requirements you may have are quotes, parentheses, and other interpunction - but those come with additional bagage - like what about `'"hi(("` - probably not a match, but how to tell it apart from `'Please reply (hi, by the way)'`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to first find all the words in the text using regex, then check each of them:

```
import re

phrases = ['hello', 'hi', 'bye']
def match(text: str) -> bool:
    return any(word in phrases for word in re.findall(r'\w+', text))

print(match("hi there, how are you?"))
print(match("hithere, how are you?"))
```